# Setting equal Height Columns on window resize with jQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am trying to equalize the heights of columns using jQuery. My solution works great on page load, but not on window resize. Code below:

```
function equalizeCols(){
        var tallest = 0;
        var program = $("#programs li");
        var blueSpace = $("#programs li .programInfo");

        program.each(function(){
            var thisHeight = $(this).height();
            var imgHeight = $("#programs li img").height();
            var leftOver = thisHeight - imgHeight;

            if(leftOver > tallest){
                tallest = leftOver;
            }
        });
        blueSpace.height(tallest);
    }

$(window).load(equalizeCols);
```

Simply enough, this iterates over all list items, gets the tallest height and then sets all of the list items to this height. Each list item has a percentage width, so the height of each will change depending on the size of the window. That said, I need this to work on window resize. If I simply do `$(window).resize(equalizeCols);` the list items will continue to grow and grow because the height is already set from load.

Any idea how I can adapt this code to work on window resize?

Comment: Are you sure javascript is the right way to solve your problem? Could it not be done with CSS? Your JS solution might turn out fragile no matter what, when it is percentage based.

Comment: I cannot think of a good CSS solution here. Any ideas (without using flexbox)?

Comment: @jchase  I have a CSS based solution at http://bit.ly/12Rghfn . While the question was Bootstrap specific, the solution is general.

Comment: SUre, it goes back to the negative margin / padding solution. HAving trouble getting it to work with my code, Ill put a fiddle together

Comment: That works if you have one row of columns. I could potentially have 50 rows, and I want the height to equalize

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    equalizeCols();
});
```

I'm not sure if that'll fire differently than your code or not. Let me know and I'll try to come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: I tried this, but it makes no difference. Mine was just a shorter way of writing the same thing. I updated my code to show its current progress